# Working with videoview inside Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I want to insert videoview to my recyclerview.I have url of view,but when I tried to do this,I see black figure of the videoview inside my recyclerview.I want to see video but not playing,just stopped video.
my adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.VideoViewHolder> {
    List<Video> call;
    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Video> call){
        this.call = call;

    }
    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_row,parent,false);
        VideoViewHolder videoViewHolder = new VideoViewHolder(v);
        return videoViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String video_url = call.get(position).getClipUrl();
        Log.d("Recycler Adapter", "videourl " + video_url);
holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_url));
        Log.d("Recycler Adapter", "title " + call.get(position).getTitle());
        Log.d("Recycler Adapter", "video_like " + call.get(position).getScore());

        holder.video_name.setText(call.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.video_like.setText(String.valueOf(call.get(position).getScore()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return call.size();
    }

    public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cardView;
        VideoView videoView;
        TextView video_name;
        TextView video_like;
        public VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            videoView = (VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            video_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Videoname_textView);
            video_like = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_textview);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLxMu.jpg)

Comment: use `TextureView` instead

Comment: Okay,thanks. Its work

Comment: I am used TextureView but whenever i am calling notifyDataSetChanged its onSurfaceTextureDestroyed callback called. @pskink

Answer (score 0):

Use seek to put it on a specific second like this:

```
videoView.seekTo(requiredTime);
```

`requireTime` is the time of the picture that will be seen

Comment: this work ın first view seen, but it not work after second view seen

Comment: Becasue of onBindViewHolder isnot called on swipe